# how to use mahout java api to convert lucene index to vector?

Tags: lucene, indexing, mahout

When i try to convert lucene index to vector, I use command line
`/bin/mahout lucene.vector` to convert to sequence file.  Is there a Java API for this kind of task?

Comment: I was just looking for this solution too.

Comment: I edited your question to be more clear. Do try to make your questions more detailed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a [solution](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/integration/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/utils/vectors/lucene/Driver.java) that might help me (and you) get there. In Driver.java, there is a `main()` method that shows how they do it. You need to setup all the configurations and then call `luceneDriver.dumpVectors()` which should dump out to a directory.

Answer (score 0):

It may be to late but the answer can be found here :
https://blog.trifork.com/tag/apache-hadoop/
also chapter six at the book Taming Text will help, i think you can find it as an example chapter on the web .

hope that someone will find it useful .